# Validate "insert", "update", "delete" in the body of a trigger

Tags: oracle, query, trigger

I need to create a query where I can remove triggers that have "insert", "update" or "delete" in their body from the result.

I'm using the following query for this

```sql
SELECT OWNER, NAME, TYPE
FROM DBA_SOURCE
WHERE TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
  AND (
    UPPER(TEXT) NOT LIKE '%INSERT%'
    OR UPPER(TEXT) NOT LIKE '%DELETE%'
    OR UPPER(TEXT) NOT LIKE '%UPDATE%'
  )
GROUP BY OWNER, NAME, TYPE
ORDER BY OWNER;
```

However, even with the filter, the triggers are returned with these values.

Is there any other way I can get this result?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two query blocks, either using `NOT EXISTS`, `NOT IN`, an outer join or a `MINUS` as here:

```
SELECT OWNER, NAME, TYPE
FROM DBA_SOURCE
WHERE TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
MINUS
SELECT OWNER, NAME, TYPE
FROM DBA_SOURCE
WHERE TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
  AND (
    UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%INSERT%'
    OR UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%DELETE%'
    OR UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%UPDATE%'
  )
ORDER BY OWNER;
```

Or,

```
SELECT owner,trigger_name
FROM dba_triggers
WHERE (owner,trigger_name) NOT IN (SELECT OWNER, NAME
                                    FROM DBA_SOURCE
                                    WHERE TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
                                      AND (
                                        UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%INSERT%'
                                        OR UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%DELETE%'
                                        OR UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%UPDATE%'
                                      ))
ORDER BY OWNER;
```

Etc. Lots of variations of this are possible.

Since your `LIKE` tests are at the line level, and what you want is to know whether *no* lines had matches, you need to test at the trigger level across *all* its lines. A two-pass query such as this one is the simplest method. You could alternatively do it in a single pass with aggregates and moving conditional logic into the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT OWNER, NAME, TYPE,MAX(CASE WHEN (UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%INSERT%'
                                        OR UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%DELETE%'
                                        OR UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%UPDATE%'
                                      ) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) has_dml
          FROM DBA_SOURCE
          WHERE TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
          GROUP BY OWNER, NAME, TYPE)
 WHERE has_dml = 'N'
```

That collapses the test of each line into a composite result for the entire trigger, which you can then filter on in a parent block. (Note that this relies on the fact that Y is alphabetically greater than N, so a single Y would make the whole trigger Y. If the trigger is N, it had no rows that rendered N in that case function. You could use 0 or 1 or any other number of similar means)

Comment: Thanks for your help again Paul. Using the last query you provided, I was able to obtain the expected result.